# Painting the board by selecting $2\times 2$ type squares from the $m\times n$ type board

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem:** Initially we have an $m\times n$ board with all unit squares white. As a result, we want to paint any two squares with a common edge, one black and one white. (That is, we want to get it like a chessboard pattern after the final step.)
In each step of the painting process, a $2\times 2$ square is selected on the board and its white unit squares are painted black and its black unit squares painted white. For which $(m, n)$ pairs can the board be painted as desired?

**Note:** I solved some parts of the problem. I'm adding them to the post. Remaining part of the problem is at the bottom of the page. Thanks.

**My attempts and some parts about the solution:**

- For $4\mid m$ and $4 \mid n$, it is possible. Firstly, let's take $m=4, n=4$.

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ } \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ } \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ } \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ } \\ \hline
\end{array}
\to 
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \blacksquare & \blacksquare & \text{ } & \text{ } \\ \hline
 \blacksquare & \blacksquare & \text{ } & \text{ } \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ } & \blacksquare & \blacksquare \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ } & \blacksquare & \blacksquare \\ \hline
\end{array}
\to
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \blacksquare & \text{ } & \blacksquare & \text{ } \\ \hline
 \blacksquare& \text{ } & \blacksquare & \text{ } \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \blacksquare & \text{ } & \blacksquare \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \blacksquare & \text{ } & \blacksquare \\ \hline
\end{array}
\to
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \blacksquare & \text{ } & \blacksquare & \text{ } \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \blacksquare & \text{ } & \blacksquare \\ \hline
 \blacksquare & \text{ } & \blacksquare & \text{ } \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \blacksquare & \text{ } & \blacksquare \\ \hline
\end{array}
$
That is, a $4 \times 4$ board can be paint as desired. Easily, we expand that, if $4\mid m$ and $4\mid n$ then a $m \times n$ board can be paint as desired.

- If $m=2$ or $n=2$, $m \times n$ board can not be paint as desired. Let $m=2$.
  \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   \text{x} & \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ }& \text{ } & \text{ } \\ \hline
   \text{x} & \text{ } & \text{ } & \text{ }& \text{ } & \text{ } \\ \hline
  \end{array}

Let's examine the first column of the $2\times n$ table (Cells with x in them). Since the colors of these cells will always be the same, a desired format cannot be done.

- If $m$ or $n$ is an odd number, a painting in the desired format can not be done. Suppose that $m \geq 3$ odd number. Let's examine difference of number of white squares and number of black squares in the first two columns. Let $w, b$ be number of white squares and number of black squares in the first two columns. Difference of they is $D = w- b$.

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{ } & \text{ }  \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ }  \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ }  \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ }  \\ \hline
\text{ } & \text{ }  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$
Initially $D = 2m - 0 = 2m$.

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{ } & \blacksquare  \\ \hline
 \blacksquare & \text{ }  \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \blacksquare  \\ \hline
 \blacksquare & \text{ }  \\ \hline
\text{ } & \blacksquare  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$
After the final step $D= m - m = 0$.

We will prove that $D$ is an invariant in $\mod 4$. Because,

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{ } & \text{ }  \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ }  \\ \hline
\end{array}
\to
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \blacksquare & \blacksquare   \\ \hline
 \blacksquare  & \blacksquare   \\ \hline
\end{array}
$
After the step, $D$ will decrease $8$.

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \blacksquare & \text{ }  \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ }  \\ \hline
\end{array}
\to
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{ } & \blacksquare   \\ \hline
 \blacksquare  & \blacksquare   \\ \hline
\end{array}
$
After the step, $D$ will decrease $4$.

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \blacksquare & \blacksquare  \\ \hline
 \text{ } & \text{ }  \\ \hline
\end{array}
\to
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{ } & \text{ }   \\ \hline
 \blacksquare  & \blacksquare   \\ \hline
\end{array}
$
After the step, $D$ will same...etc.

Thus, $D$ is an invariant in $\mod 4$.
When $m\geq 3$ odd number, initially $D = 2m \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ and after the final step $D\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Since $2\not\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, there is a contradiction. That is, when $m$ or $n$ is an odd number, a painting in the desired format can not be done.

**Remaining Problem:** Let $m,n>2$ even numbers.

(a) If $m\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ and $n\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$, can we paint in the desired format?

(b) If $m\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ and $n\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, can we paint in the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** As you noticed, you need some sort of invariant to prove you cannot succeed. You used the difference $b-w$ for the squares in *two* columns. Instead, find a modulo invariant for the number of black squares alone in a *single* column.

Comment: Examining the first column solves the remaining problem, thanks a lot.